# Magento Google API for Shopping ImageLink.php Parent Image

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I've implemented the Google Content API to my Magento store and have it working fairly well thus far but i need to resolve an issue where a simle product needs to use it's parent image.

This is the function from ImageLink.php of the GoogleShopping module:

```
    public function convertAttribute($product, $entry)
{
            $url = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getImageUrl($product);
            if ($product->getImage() && $product->getImage() != 'no_selection' && $url) {
                    $this->_setAttribute($entry, 'image_link', self::ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_URL, $url);
                } 
    return $entry;
}
```

I've then attempted to modify this to grab the parents image if there is a parent, like this:

```
    public function convertAttribute($product, $entry)
{
            $parentIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($product);
            if ($parentIds[0] != '') {
                $product = $parentIds[0]; 
            }
            $url = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getImageUrl($product);
            if ($product->getImage() && $product->getImage() != 'no_selection' && $url) {
                    $this->_setAttribute($entry, 'image_link', self::ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_URL, $url);
                } 
    return $entry;
}
```

But this appears to fail. I think the reason is that i can't tell what the variable $product actually is. I've tried writing it to a file but don't get any output..

Has anyone tackled this before or have some idea how to go about fixing it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Cracked it. My code was a little off.

This should help alot of others who need help tweeking the google api featuer in magento so here is what i've done o get this working:

```
    public function convertAttribute($product, $entry)
{
            $parentIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId());
            if ($parentIds[0] != '') {
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($parentIds[0]); 
            }
            $url = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getImageUrl($product);
            if ($product->getImage() && $product->getImage() != 'no_selection' && $url) {
                    $this->_setAttribute($entry, 'image_link', self::ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_URL, $url);
                }  
    return $entry;
}
```

You should be able to use similar modifications to get other parent items for the URL for example.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function convertAttribute($product, $entry)
{
        $parentIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId());
        if ($parentIds[0] != '' && $product->getImage() == 'no_selection') {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($parentIds[0]); 
        }
        $url = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getImageUrl($product);
        if ($product->getImage() && $product->getImage() != 'no_selection' && $url) {
                $this->_setAttribute($entry, 'image_link', self::ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_URL, $url);
            }  
return $entry;
}
```

I modified this just a bit. i wanted to check if the simple product had a image and if it did to go ahead an use it, so I added && $product->getImage() == 'no_selection' If the image was missing then I wanted the configurable image. I am not sure if there is a better way to do it but this seems to be working currently. Hope this helps someone. I use Magento Enterprise 1.12.